# r - padding out data in a time series with values from another data frame

Tags: r

I have semi-annual data set with names every six months.  How can I create a monthly time series with the semi-annual names from my original data frame?

To be clear I am trying to create this:

```
Date       V1     V2     -->     Date       V1   V2
Jan-2012  Name1  Name2   -->     Jan-2012  Name1  Name2
Jul-2012  Name3  Name4   -->     Feb-2012  Name1  Name2
Jan-2013  Name5  Name6   -->     Mar-2012  Name1  Name2
                                 Apr-2012  Name1  Name2
                                 May-2012  Name1  Name2
                                 Jun-2012  Name1  Name2
                                 Jul-2012  Name3  Name4
                                 etc...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach uses `tidyverse`. First, here's a dummy data frame with data every 6 months.

```
df <- data.frame(date = c(as.Date("01-Jan-2012", format = "%d-%b-%Y"), 
                          as.Date("01-Jul-2012", format = "%d-%b-%Y"), 
                          as.Date("01-Jan-2013", format = "%d-%b-%Y")),
                 foo = LETTERS[1:3],
                 bar = 1:3)

#         date foo bar
# 1 2012-01-01   A   1
# 2 2012-07-01   B   2
# 3 2013-01-01   C   3
```

Next, I create a template to be filled with rows for each month.

```
# Template to be filled
filled_df <- data.frame(date = seq(min(df$date), max(df$date), by = "month"))

#          date
# 1  2012-01-01
# 2  2012-02-01
# 3  2012-03-01
# 4  2012-04-01
# 5  2012-05-01
# 6  2012-06-01
# 7  2012-07-01
# 8  2012-08-01
# 9  2012-09-01
# 10 2012-10-01
# 11 2012-11-01
# 12 2012-12-01
# 13 2013-01-01
```

Finally, I join the original data frame to my template and fill downwards.

```
# Bind with original, then fill
filled_df %>%
  left_join(df) %>% 
  fill(foo, bar)

#          date foo bar
# 1  2012-01-01   A   1
# 2  2012-02-01   A   1
# 3  2012-03-01   A   1
# 4  2012-04-01   A   1
# 5  2012-05-01   A   1
# 6  2012-06-01   A   1
# 7  2012-07-01   B   2
# 8  2012-08-01   B   2
# 9  2012-09-01   B   2
# 10 2012-10-01   B   2
# 11 2012-11-01   B   2
# 12 2012-12-01   B   2
# 13 2013-01-01   C   3
```

Note that I add a day to my dates to avoid problems.

Comment: This is great, thanks!  How can I do the bind if the dates are rownames?  I see you have the dates as their own column.

Comment: @Dan I'd add a column, like this `df %<>% mutate(dates = rownames(df))`. Note that `%<>%` comes from the `magrittr` package.

Comment: @Dan Do your dates have a day and are they dates? Run `class(df$date)` to check. It should return `Date`. PS My comment above should read `df %<>% mutate(date = rownames(df))` -- no s on `date`.

Comment: @Dan What's `top.fund`? Note in my solution the original data frame is called `df`. If yours is called something else, either rename it to `df` or replace all the references to `df` in my code with the name of your data frame.

Comment: *Hi, Lyngbakr. I am getting a 'by' error. The data frame doesn't seem to be liking the solution: `df %<>% mutate(dates = rownames(df)) filled_df <- as.data.frame(rownames(df)) filled_df %>% left_join(df) %>% fill(foo, bar)`  Sorry, missed that.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message and in your question a snippet of data (using `dput`) that I can use to reproduce your error?

Comment: Ok, so my dates were being returned as characters, because they were DD/MM/YYYY.  In trying to correct this, I've broken the code: `df %>% mutate(date = rownames(df)) df <- as.Date(df$date, "%d/%m/%y") filled_df <- as.data.frame(rownames(df)) filled_df %>% left_join(df) %>% fill(foo, bar)`

Comment: and it kicks back: Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars"): no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "Date"

Comment: Maybe `df %<>% mutate(date = as.Date(rownames(df), "%d/%m/%Y"))` instead of `df %>% mutate(date = rownames(df)) df <- as.Date(df$date, "%d/%m/%y")`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe a custom function can help you, in conjunction with `mapply()`. This example reproduces your original data frame and then applies the custom function, ending with a combined, single data frame to match the desired result.

```
# PRODUCING THE ORIGINAL DATA FRAME
df = data.frame(
  Date = c(
    format(as.Date("2012-01-01"),"%b-%Y"),
    format(as.Date("2012-07-01"),"%b-%Y"),
    format(as.Date("2013-01-01"),"%b-%Y")
  ),
  V1 = c("Name1","Name3","Name5"),
  V2 = c("Name2","Name4","Name6"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

df
      Date    V1    V2
1 Jan-2012 Name1 Name2
2 Jul-2012 Name3 Name4
3 Jan-2013 Name5 Name6


# RESTRUCTURING
createSet = function(Date,V1,V2){
  dat = as.Date(paste0(df$Date,"-01"),"%b-%Y-%d")
  dat = format(seq(dat,by="month",length.out=6),"%b-%Y")
  data.frame(Date=dat,V1=V1,V2=V2)
}
z = mapply(createSet,df$Date,df$V1,df$V2,SIMPLIFY=F)
do.call("rbind",z)


# RESULTING DATA FRAME
       Date    V1    V2
1  Jan-2012 Name1 Name2
2  Feb-2012 Name1 Name2
3  Mar-2012 Name1 Name2
4  Apr-2012 Name1 Name2
5  May-2012 Name1 Name2
6  Jun-2012 Name1 Name2
7  Jul-2012 Name3 Name4
8  Aug-2012 Name3 Name4
9  Sep-2012 Name3 Name4
10 Oct-2012 Name3 Name4
11 Nov-2012 Name3 Name4
12 Dec-2012 Name3 Name4
13 Jan-2013 Name5 Name6
14 Feb-2013 Name5 Name6
15 Mar-2013 Name5 Name6
16 Apr-2013 Name5 Name6
17 May-2013 Name5 Name6
18 Jun-2013 Name5 Name6
```